# TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable

Tags: python, generator, yield

I have a generator defined like this:

```
def lengths(x):
    for k, v in x.items():
        yield v['time_length']
```

And it works, calling it with

```
for i in lengths(x):
    print i
```

produces:

```
3600
1200
3600
300
```

which are the correct numbers.

However, when I call it like so:

```
somefun(lengths(x))
```

where `somefun()` is defined as:

```
def somefun(lengths):
    for length in lengths():  # <--- ERROR HERE
        if not is_blahblah(length): return False
```

I get this error message:

```
TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You don't need to call your generator, remove the `()` brackets.

You are probably confused by the fact that you use the same name for the variable inside the function as the name of the generator; the following will work too:

```
def somefun(lengen):
    for length in lengen:
        if not is_blahblah(length): return False
```

A parameter passed to the `somefun` function is then bound to the local `lengen` variable instead of `lengths`, to make it clear that that local variable is not the same thing as the `lengths()` function you defined elsewhere.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant, what was the logic to put the parentheses there in the first place?

Comment: @unkulunkulu: probably confusion with the function name that produces the generator.

Comment: @unkulunkulu - logic? You ask a raving, confused beginner about logic. :)

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant pretend `lengths` returns a list, instead of `yield`ing. `somefun`, as defined, doesn't know any different.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant, :) logic is a great tool for a begginer. I mean, parameters to functions work close to 'replace with'. So if you replaced your `lengths` parameter with what you supply to the function (`lengths(x)`), then you would get `for length in lengths(x)():` line, looks weird right :)

Comment: @unkulunkulu, btw, I most recently come from PHP. Try logic there and you are toast... :-)

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant, then we are welcoming you in the warm lands of python where logic works and programmers are happy.